# Perl Syntax for Net::SSLeay variable assignment within a "perl -e" string (which is itself within a script)

Tags: perl, syntax, openssl

The following excerpt is from the https.monitor from the freeware `mon` monitoring program.

```
$result = `$perl -e'use Net::SSLeay ; Net::SSLeay::SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms() ; print join("$field_delim",Net::SSLeay::get_https("$site", "$port", "$path"))'`;
```

Some of the HTTPS servers being monitored are not compatible with OpenSSL (Net::SSLeay) with autodetect and/or TLS so the Net::SSLeay::ssl_version variable needs to be changed explicitly to v3.

The following works as expected from a command line and explicitly changes ssl_version to 3:

```
perl -e 'use Net::SSLeay; Net::SSLeay::SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms() ; $Net::SSLeay::ssl_version = 3 ; print join("<>",Net::SSLeay::get_https("server.domain.internal", "443", "/"))'
```

I cannot get this to work in the original line in the https.monitor perl file.
As written above, perl will advise of the following error:

`Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near "3 ;"`

I have tried all manner of syntax to get this line to compile and for the ssl_version setting to take, but I can't seem to get both to happen at once. Using "=>" syntax for the Net::SSLeay::ssl_version variable assignment I can get it to compile but the setting doesn't appear to "take". I have used $Net::SSLeay::ssl_version and "$Net::SSLeay::ssl_version", curly braces around the variable, etc, but I can't get this to work right.

What should the syntax be for "Net::SSLeay::ssl_version = 3" in the "perl -e" line within a perl script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $result = `perl -e'... \$Net::SSLeay::ssl_version = 3; ...'`;
```

That's too easy to get wrong though. You can properly quote for unix shells using [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aShellQuote)'s `shell_quote`.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote(
    $perl,
    -e => <<'__EOI__',
        use Net::SSLeay;
        my ($field_delim, $site, $port, $path) = @ARGV;
        Net::SSLeay::SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
        $Net::SSLeay::ssl_version = 3;
        print join($field_delim, Net::SSLeay::get_https($site, $port, $path));
__EOI__
    '--',
    $field_delim, $site, $port, $path,
);

my $result = `$cmd`;
```

You can avoid the shell entirely using [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aSimple)'s `capturex`.

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my @cmd = (
    $perl,
    -e => <<'__EOI__',
        use Net::SSLeay;
        my ($field_delim, $site, $port, $path) = @ARGV;
        Net::SSLeay::SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
        $Net::SSLeay::ssl_version = 3;
        print join($field_delim, Net::SSLeay::get_https($site, $port, $path));
__EOI__
    '--',
    $field_delim, $site, $port, $path,
);

my $result = capturex(@cmd);
```

Bonus: `capturex` does the error checking for you! Using the first two methods, you'd need at least the following:

```
die $! if $? == -1;
die "Killed by signal ".($? & 127) if $? & 127;
die "Exited with error ".($? >> 8) if $? >> 8;
```

Comment: The "\$" did not work in the "my $result = ..." line, but the shell_quote and capturex's did work as written. While these were great answers, what is the best way to preserve the $field_delim, $site, $port, and $path variables in either shellquote or catpturex? The hard coded "<>", "server.domain.internal", "443, "/" were useful for testing, but in reality the monitor is passed parameters that change on each execution.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answers.